# Datatables has only 10 rows accessible outside the DataTables creation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I am using Django and in one of my tamplates I use datatables (1.10.19) to display my table data. 
This is how my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                { title: "Naslov zahtjeva" },
                { title: "Datum slanja" },
                { title: "Status" },
                { title: "Rok Izvršenja." },
                { title: "Id zahtjeva" },
            ],
            "fnCreatedRow": function(row, data, index){
                $(row).addClass("clickable-row");
                $(row).attr('data-href', data[4]);
                $(row).addClass("table_row_point");
            },
        });
```

Problem occurs at the line -> $(row).attr('data-href', data[4]);
I have a different function that is suposed to use that 'ID' from 'data-href' attribute in order to go to another page like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("href");
        });
    });
```

Thing is it works fine for first 10 rows, and when I try 'console.log( this );' I get [image]

Only for the first 10 rows, and it acts like other 3000 don't even exist, I believe it is connected to the default value of 10 rows that appear, but it makes no sense to me for data to be displayed normally, but the 'tr' element not to exist for all, but 10 of them.

Note: When I place this function into DataTable creation code (1st snippet) it shows all the tr elements

`$('#mytable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () { 
                console.log( this ); 
            } );`

If someone has any idea it would be much appreciated

Comment: It is definitely connected to the "pageLength" attribute, only renders the amount it loads into accessible code outside of the DataTables creation function...

Comment: Since you already found about event delegation and you know that only `pageLength` amount of row is rendered per DataTable "page"... What exactly is your question?

Comment: So whats not working? does the function not get called when you move to the second page and the next rows are created? I was under the impression that unless you specifically set the defer render option to false DT should create all rows up front (when using ajax or JS datasource) https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender. Presumably though this is not happenin

Comment: There is no noticable issue on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oPByvP?editors=0011) where I "simulated" your 3000 rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

`fnCreatedRow` function is executed everytime datatable creates the `<tr>` element in the dom. Since you have enabled pagination, function is run only on the `<tr>` elements created at the time. If you move on to next page, you'll see that console prints next set of rows.

By the way I think `createdRow` is preferred over old `fnCreatedRow` naming convention. https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow

Comment: I tried with bot of them, and both don't do jack. I am not sure what you mean because if I run it (with both createdRow or fnCreatedRow) it logs all the rows at once, nothing happens when I change the page in the console though.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. If you have set to display 10 rows at a time in a page, datatables will execute `fnCreatedRow` only 10 times for the rows displayed. what are you trying to achieve?